# Hot to get all the images to display without reloading the page in PHP?

Tags: php, ajax

After User Clicks Sumbit Button Data passes through one half of the path to images and then the code below links it to the second half. I want to know how I can display all this without Page Reload? I know it might be done with AJAX but I have no idea on how to do so. So please can someone help?

```
<?php

$albumnamepath = $_POST['field'];

echo $albumnamepath;

$display = "SELECT * FROM paths WHERE user_id = '$session_user_id' AND album_name = '$albumnamepath'";

$result = mysql_query($display); 

echo "<table>";

$i = 0;

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {

        if ($i % 4 == 0) { //3 == 0.

          echo '<tr>';
    }

       echo "<td>".'

                   <ul class="img-list">
                   <li><div class="picbox"><a href="'.$albumnamepath.$row['location'].'" class="swipebox" title="'.$row['caption'].'"><img src="'.$albumnamepath.$row['thumbnail'].'"><span class="text-content"><span>'.$row['caption'].'</span></span>'."</a></li>
                   </ul>

              </td>";

            //echo '<a href="'.$albumnamepath.$row['location'].'" class="swipebox" title="'.$row['caption'].'"><img src="'.$albumnamepath.$row['thumbnail'].'">';

           if ($i % 4 == 3) { //3 == 2.

             echo '</tr>';

               }
              $i++; 
}

//Here is a check in case there is not a multiple of 3 images in a row.
if ($i % 4 != 0) { //4 != 0.
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Just as an additional pointer, you should use PDO or mysqli rather than mysql_* to access your database. When you use mysql_* (as you are in the above code block) you leave your database open to sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Ajax would help you very much, since you'll be using ajax to get, essentially, the entire page. Ajax is usually used if you want to change a part of the page, and the data either has to come from the server real-time (i.e. after the page is loaded), or is expensive to calculate or deliver in full (e.g. a very long, or infinite list, and if most users only use a small amount). Otherwise, it's more efficient to send all the data in one go, and then manipulate it in the browser.

I would suggest the following approach: divide the table rows into groups of table rows; e.g. 5 rows (chosen arbitrarily). Change the block of code where you echo '' to:

```
    if ($i % 4 == 0) { //3 == 0.
        $block=ceil($i/(4*5));
        echo '<tr class="block_$block">';
    }
```

This means each block of 5 rows (by 4 across) will be a different class - "block_1", "block_2" and so forth.

Then, you can hide and display blocks using Javascript. To hide a block, use the following javascript code:

```
var trToHide = document.getElementsByClassName("block_1");

for(var i = 0; i < trToHide.length; i++) {
    trToHide[i].style.display="none";
}
```

To unhide a block:

```
var trToHide = document.getElementsByClassName("block_3");

for(var i = 0; i < trToHide.length; i++) {
    trToHide[i].style.display="block";
}
```

Obviously, you will want to use variables to keep track of which block is displayed; then you can have a "Next" and "Back" button, which hides the current block, adds/subtracts one, then displays the (new) current block. You will also want to have all blocks except the first one hidden at the start. Left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**

You have to use ajax request.

You use form to set filters? Then you can use `.ajaxSumbit` (but you need [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) for it).

Also, you can add form submit handler, where you will prevent form default submit action and send ajax request instead of it. Look this example:

File `getImages.php`:

```
// in this file you will do same actions as you do now to output table with images
```

**Note**, that `getImages.php` must contain only table with results or message, that there are no results.

File with form, where you set filters:

```
// some html with forms etc
<form id='myForm'>
// some inputs etc
</form>
<div id='results'></div>
```

And javascript:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(e) { // use e parameter for preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "path/to/getImages.php",
           data: $("#myForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               $("#results").html(data);
           }
         });

    return false; // <-- deny sumitting from and reloading page
    //e.preventDefault(); // <-- this do same as `return false;` <-- deny sumitting from and reloading page
});
```

**Explanation:**

Browser load page with form, where you can set filters. User sets filters and pressing button `submit`. Browser will send ajax request to file `getImages.php` with some parameters (filters, user set filter before sending the form). This script generates some output with table, with img tags etc and return it. Browser receives this output and puts it to element with id `#results`:

```
<div id='results'></div>
                  ^
------------------^
```

Data, generated by script `getImages.php` will be inserted here.

So, filtered images will be received and shown without page reload :)

Is it what you need?

Hope this will help you.

Comment: What do you mean by 'You use form to set filters?', I do not think I have that. Otherwise this is what my form looks like:
//Display all the album names:
$select_album_names = "SELECT * FROM albums WHERE user_id = '$session_user_id'";
$album_names = mysql_query($select_album_names);
while($display_album_names = mysql_fetch_array($album_names))
  {
 echo "<tr><td>".'<input type="radio" name="field" id="radio'.$i.'" value="'.$display_album_names['path'].'" onclick="this.form.submit();">'.'<label for="radio'.$i.'">'.$display_album_names['name'].'</label>'."</td></tr>";
$i++;
  }